# Unable to access images from server nested folders ampps

Tags: image, http-status-code-404, ampps

I have installed the ampps server and I have project in www folder of ampps i.e. IntraApp. I have another folder of photogallery in IntraApp and another nested folders then the images in the folder.

I am not able to access the images from nested folder it shows the error 404 page not found though the images are present in folder and path is correct.

If I keep image in IntraApp folder I am able to access it but not from the nested folders. Also the php file gets run if it is in nested folder.

http://103.91.100.17:60/IntraApp/photogallery/ExpressYourself/BestWishes/appriciate.jpg

This path gives 404 error.

[image]

Though the file is present in that path.

Not getting what is the issue here. Please help. thank you.